# Filter by elements in an Array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a JSON File with Tasks. They are structured as follows:

```
[
{
    "id":"1",
    "name":"task1",
    "tags":["tag1","tag2","tag3"]
},
{
    "id":"2",
    "name":"task2",
    "tags":["tag4","tag2","tag5"]
},
{
    "id":"3",
    "name":"task3",
    "tags":["tag3"]
}
]
```

Here's a Plunkr for what I want
http://plnkr.co/edit/kMhiHDyybHYxGfV7W39z?p=preview

Basically, this is what I want : http://jsfiddle.net/TahmidTanzim/N9Vqk/

I've looked through various SO questions and they all suggest I am doing it right. 
However I don't understand where I am going wrong. I want only those tasks that contain the selectedTag to be displayed in the red list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change filters to compare inner tags using arrays.

```
myapp.filter('tagFilter',function()
{
    return function(Data,selectedTags)
    {
        if(selectedTags.length===0) return Data;
        var tempData=[];
        for(var i  in Data) {
            for(var z in Data[i].tags) {
                for(var k in selectedTags) {
                    var value = selectedTags[k];
                    if(value == Data[i].tags[z]) {
                        tempData.push(Data[i]);
                        break;             
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return tempData;
    }
});
```

Comment: The Plunkr is working fine, but it seems that the filter in not able to get selectedTags array. I tried console.log(selectedTags) in the filter and it comes up empty in my actual app!

Comment: I have just edited the code, I have tested in Plunker. Could you try again ?

Comment: Did you try to change your angular version (using the same as plunker) ?

Comment: The plunker seems to work. But In my actual app, I am unable to pass selectedTags to the filter. While trying to print out selectedTags in the filter, I get an empty array. However, I can print out the selectedTags array from SetSetectedTags() function.

Comment: You are correct. I am using an older version of AngularJS!

Comment: Updating to the latest version also couldn't solve the problem!